# Get more than 25 comments on instagram API

Tags: api, facebook, graph, instagram

I am using this url for get request -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/${ig_media.id}/comments?access_token=${config.userAccessToken}
```

But it is returning only 25 comments. What can I do to get more comments?

Here ig_media.id is media ID of instagram, which is required to get comments on a media, where media can be posts of pictures or videos on instagram.

userAccessToken is the access token required to do the following api request on Instagram.

Comment: Add `limit=...` to your query string parameters. (Different endpoints have different max values for that, so even if you specify a really large limit, you might not get all the data in one go. In that case, you simply will _have to_ use pagination.)

Comment: You should explain the details. It's not a proper question.

Comment: @Tugrul I have edited the question, is it more clear now?

Comment: Thats ok for the first question @AmanBhadauria

Comment: @CBroe I tried using limit, it can return 50 comments now, can we get higher?

Comment: As I said, different endpoints have different max. limits. If you are not getting more than 50 from this one even with a higher limit - then you will have to paginate.

Answer (score 0):

It also gives you a after parsing like that use that for further record.
For reference it will like that...

```html
 "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "QVFIUjRPWGRFU3NVejFma29QeGtwVTA2Y1o1bW5vVGRFS1FkeTdKZAW1VSU5nMG5DbzJBWEJGcnFlVU05SlFCR0ZAvVXU2dGlYZA3lZAbXMzbzhfNkVQZAktEWlBn",
            "after": "QVFIUlZApd01xQXlFbHc0eTYwMEloVWFoVDFLVzllbXlRUlFQUmlIUUQteUl1Sy1fTF9Odk1SMjVHWk9IYUJiS2ZAiODVUZAllpWUtuZA0NfTjVTRnRQQS1vN25R"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Instagram Allow max 25records at one go.. and return before and after paging with it for further records..

Answer (score 0):

It also gives you a after parsing like that use that for further record. For reference it will like that...

```html
"paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "QVFIUjRPWGRFU3NVejFma29QeGtwVTA2Y1o1bW5vVGRFS1FkeTdKZAW1VSU5nMG5DbzJBWEJGcnFlVU05SlFCR0ZAvVXU2dGlYZA3lZAbXMzbzhfNkVQZAktEWlBn",
            "after": "QVFIUlZApd01xQXlFbHc0eTYwMEloVWFoVDFLVzllbXlRUlFQUmlIUUQteUl1Sy1fTF9Odk1SMjVHWk9IYUJiS2ZAiODVUZAllpWUtuZA0NfTjVTRnRQQS1vN25R"
        },
```